# Perl get user, group and file permission and assign to variable

Tags: perl

I am having a below code which gets a file's user, group and permission.

```
use File::stat;

my $filename = "/home/chetanv/filecheck";

my $mode = (stat($filename));
my $user = getpwuid(@$mode[4]);
my $group = getgrgid(@$mode[5]);

printf "Permission : %04o\n", @$mode[2] & 07777;
print "User : $user\n";
print "Group : $group\n";
```

OUTPUT for the same:

```
Permission : 0777
User : chetanv
Group : wheel
```

The below line works fine because i use printf statement

```
printf "Permission : %04o\n", @$mode[2] & 07777;
```

Now if i am trying to assign it to a variable for future use i am unable to do it. I tried something like this:

```
my $mode = (stat($filename));
my $perm = "%04o\n", @$mode[2] & 07777;
my $user = getpwuid(@$mode[4]);
my $group = getgrgid(@$mode[5]);
print "Perm : $perm\n";
print "User : $user\n";
print "Group : $group\n";
```

It says,

```
Useless use of bitwise and (&) in void context
```

Can someone help me on how i can assign the permission output to a variable and use the variable later

Comment: You need `sprintf` there in your `my $perm` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> my $perm = "%04o\n", @$mode[2] & 07777;
> ```

You are missing an [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) call here. In your example above you had [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html), which formats and prints. If you only want to format and assign, you have to use `sprintf`. That will make the error go away.

Furthermore, your `stat` call returns an object because you are using [File::stat](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::stat). You shouldn't be using the underlying array structure, but rather the accessors.

```
my $stat = stat $filename;
my $perm = sprintf "%04o\n", $stat->mode & 07777;
```

Note how I also renamed it to `$stat`, because the object holds all of the information regarding that file's `stat` call, not only the mode. You can use it throughout your program to increase readability.

Comment: Re "*You shouldn't be using the underlying array structure, but rather the accessors*", Indeed. There's no point is using File::stat if one keeps using array offsets. The whole reason File::stat exists is to give readable names to the fields so one doesn't have to use numerical offsets!

Comment: The rest of the program should be using the object returned from `File::stat` too, and it shouldn't be called `$mode`. With `my $st = stat $filename`, the other values can be accessed with `$st->mode & 07777`, `$st->uid`, and `$st->gid`.